# When using filesystemwatcher why when trying to detect downloaded files as created its only detecting renamed?

Tags: c#, winforms

When i check the chexkbox for created there is no monitoring even if new files have been downloaded to the monitoring folder.

[image: monitoring for created(downloaded) files but its not showing anything]

when checking the renamed checkbox then its start showing for each downloaded file this but i don't understand why and what is it doing. on the hard drive i see the regular downloaded fbx files nothing renamed.

[image: monitoring renamed files]

what I want to do is to monitor the downloaded files(created i think is the right one) and then each file created then copy the file to another folder and delete the file from the original downloaded folder.

but before doing the copying and deleting part it's not even monitoring right.

this is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FileSysMon
{
    public partial class frmFileSysMon : Form
    {
        public frmFileSysMon()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Sample 01: Declarations.
        private string content = "";
        private string last_event_filename = "";

        //Sample 02: Close the form
        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fileMon.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            this.Close();
        }

        //Sample 03: Clear Text Content
        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        //Sample 04: Do it recursively
        private void chkRecursive_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkRecursive.Checked == true )
                fileMon.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            else
                fileMon.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        }

        //Sample 05: Set the Path to Spy using Folder Browser Dialog
        private void btnPickFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FolderB.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtFolderPath.Text = FolderB.SelectedPath;
                fileMon.Path = txtFolderPath.Text;
            }
        }

        //Sample 06: Enable capturing file system events
        private void btnMonitor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fileMon.Path = txtFolderPath.Text;
            fileMon.Filter = "*.fbx";
            txtDisplay.AppendText("Monitoring for fbx type files. Started at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            txtDisplay.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            fileMon.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        //Sample 07: Enable capturing file system events
        private void txtFolderPath_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFolderPath.Text))
                chkRecursive.Enabled = false;
            else
                chkRecursive.Enabled = true;
        }

        //Sample 08: Monitor all the File Events
        private void fileMon_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //!under_modification: Avoids repeated consecutive ourput of Files changed per file
            if (chkModified.CheckState == CheckState.Checked && last_event_filename != e.FullPath)
            {
                content = "File Changed: " + e.FullPath + Environment.NewLine;
                txtDisplay.AppendText(content);
            }
            last_event_filename = e.FullPath;
        }

        private void fileMon_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkCreated.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                content = "File Created: " + e.FullPath + Environment.NewLine;
                txtDisplay.AppendText(content);
            }
            last_event_filename = e.FullPath;
        }

        private void fileMon_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkDeleted.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                content = "File Deleted: " + e.FullPath + Environment.NewLine;
                txtDisplay.AppendText(content);
            }
            last_event_filename = e.FullPath;
        }

        private void fileMon_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkRenamed.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                content = "File Renamed: New Name - "+  e.FullPath + " Old Name : " + e.OldFullPath 
                    + Environment.NewLine;
                txtDisplay.AppendText(content);
            }
            last_event_filename = e.FullPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Tried the above , tried to monitor downloaded files but its monitoring renamed files.

Comment: There is code in the designer.cs file that is doing a lot of the work.  The designer file registers the event ("+=) which is calling the event methods.  The is a form_load that is registering the events.  You can open the designer.cs file to see the code.

Comment: Note that the file created event may fire before the file is fully written and closed. So, be cautious when using it. If the file is renamed after creation `Renamed` is the better event to look for.